# Yarn workspace and angular "Cannot locate the 'node_modules' directory."

Tags: angular, yarn-workspaces

After attempting to switch a project over to using yarn workspaces, i can't seem to get the angular compiler command to work. I have tried using the yarn dlx command to use the angular compiler version that should be installed for the specific workspace that the command is run in, but angular/yarn throws the error

```
 YN0000: > yarn dlx -p @angular/cli ng build --prod && npm run merge && npm run clean
➤ YN0000: 
➤ YN0000: ➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0000: ➤ YN0061: │ request@npm:2.88.2 is deprecated: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
➤ YN0000: ➤ YN0061: │ uuid@npm:3.4.0 is deprecated: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
➤ YN0000: ➤ YN0061: │ har-validator@npm:5.1.5 is deprecated: this library is no longer supported
➤ YN0000: ➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1s 312ms
➤ YN0000: ➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0000: ➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: ➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: ➤ YN0007: │ @angular/cli@npm:12.0.3 must be built because it never did before or the last one failed
➤ YN0000: ➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1s 218ms
➤ YN0000: ➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 2s 664ms
➤ YN0000: 
➤ YN0000: Your global Angular CLI version (12.0.3) is greater than your local version (10.0.8). The local Angular CLI version is used.
➤ YN0000: 
➤ YN0000: To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
➤ YN0000: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot locate the 'node_modules' directory.
➤ YN0000: See "/private/var/folders/_1/5253gc4s28l4740x6hm0b8500000gp/T/ng-mBJIHY/angular-errors.log" for further details.
➤ YN0000: Done in 20s 310ms
```

I've tried looking for a solution to this problem, but i am new to yarn version 2, and I don't understand what type of solution i need to look into to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. When working with angular and yarn workspaces, make sure that in your yarnrc.yml file you have:

```
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

This will allow for angular to resolve the modules needed. Currently this is an issue with angular.